# SQL LEFT JOIN Query not using Primary Keys is too slow, how can I speed up?

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

I have three MySQL tables; "teams" and two tables depending on team type ("team_type_1" and "team_type_2"). I'm needing to query all three tables into one table, and sum each team's miles from both of the team_type tables into one "miles" column.

My queries below work as needed but since my JOIN queries aren't using primary IDs it either locks up or takes too long.

Would be nice to use the primary IDs "team_type_1.id" and "team_type_2.id" in the JOINs but my try in the last query below is still using non-primary keys in the inner queries.  Is there a different approach I could take to speed up the query?

```
Table 1: teams (3000 total records)
id (primary) | team_name


Table 2: team_type_1 (12000 total records)
id (primary) | team_id | miles


Table 3: team_type_2 (150000 total records)
id (primary) | team_id | miles
```

---

Combine the above tables into:
team_name | miles

---

When running these queries separately using primary keys it only takes milliseconds, but I need these tables combined:

```
SELECT
teams.team_name,
SUM(team_type_1.miles)
FROM team_type_1
LEFT JOIN teams ON teams.id = team_type_1.team_id
GROUP BY team_type_1.team_id


SELECT
teams.team_name,
SUM(team_type_2.miles)
FROM team_type_2
LEFT JOIN teams ON teams.id = team_type_2.team_id
GROUP BY team_type_2.team_id
```

---

When combining, and not using primary keys, it locks up the database:

```
SELECT
teams.team_name,
SUM(CASE WHEN team_type_2.miles THEN team_type_2.miles ELSE team_type_1.miles END)
FROM teams

LEFT JOIN team_type_1 ON team_type_1.team_id = teams.id
LEFT JOIN team_type_2 ON team_type_2.team_id = teams.id

GROUP BY teams.id
```

---

This takes around 8-10 seconds to run but the inner select is using non-primary IDs; is there a way to speed this up?

```
SELECT
teams.team_name,
SUM(CASE WHEN team_type_2.miles THEN team_type_2.miles ELSE team_type_1.miles END)
FROM teams

LEFT JOIN team_type_1 ON team_type_1.id = (SELECT team_type_1.id FROM team_type_1 WHERE team_type_1.team_id = teams.id GROUP BY team_type_1.team_id)
LEFT JOIN team_type_2 ON team_type_2.id = (SELECT team_type_2.id FROM team_type_2 WHERE team_type_2.team_id = teams.id GROUP BY team_type_2.team_id)

WHERE team_type_2.miles > 0 OR team_type_1.miles > 0 GROUP BY teams.id
```

---

- UPDATE:

Thanks @Strawberry for the UNION hint, in addition the the few columns and three tables above, I also had other tables and columns I'm querying, but didn't mention those since I'm able to use the primary IDs for those.  Below is my full query structure, using UNIONS, and it is working as I needed.

```
SELECT
teams.team_name,
teams.start_date,
team_counties.county_name,
team_leagues.league_name,
SUM(team_type_1.miles)
FROM team_type_1

LEFT JOIN teams ON teams.id = team_type_1.team_id
LEFT JOIN team_counties ON team_counties.id = teams.county_id
LEFT JOIN team_leagues ON team_leagues.id = teams.league_id

GROUP BY team_type_1.team_id

UNION

SELECT
teams.team_name,
teams.start_date,
team_counties.county_name,
team_leagues.league_name,
SUM(team_type_2.miles)
FROM team_type_2

LEFT JOIN teams ON teams.id = team_type_2.team_id
LEFT JOIN team_counties ON team_counties.id = teams.county_id
LEFT JOIN team_leagues ON team_leagues.id = teams.league_id

GROUP BY team_type_2.team_id
```

Comment: I don't understand why are you're joining rather than unioning the two queries. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Ah, I worked with UNIONS for a good while but I'm also joining other tables along with other columns and kept getting a "Columns don't match" type of error.  You gave me an idea however, and I posted an update above using UNIONS that looks to work as I'm needing, and is really fast.  Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways around this, but the easiest solution is to simply [index](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/guidelines-for-sql/the-benefits-of-indexing-large-mysql-tables) the `team_id` column in the two sub-tables:

```
ALTER TABLE `team_type_1`
    ADD INDEX `team_id` (`team_id`);
ALTER TABLE `team_type_2`
    ADD INDEX `team_id` (`team_id`);
```

This should allow you to do the following with some speed:

```
SELECT teams.id,
       teams.team_name,
       SUM(IFNULL(team_type_1.miles, 0) + IFNULL(team_type_2.miles, 0)) sum_miles
FROM teams
LEFT JOIN team_type_1 ON team_type_1.team_id = teams.id
LEFT JOIN team_type_2 ON team_type_2.team_id = teams.id
GROUP BY teams.id,
         teams.team_name
```

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, the `miles` are calculation form fields that populate those columns and are text types, and not able to make them indexes to test your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, I changed the column (not primary) from non-unique index to unique index. It sped up my query by 3x. Hope, it helps someone.